# What is the RxJS way of working with snapshotChanges()?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs, refactoring

So I have an auth.service.ts, crud.service.ts, and a components.ts. While the code I have written works, it happens to be a combination of multiple tutorials and docs. I was wondering how the code below can be combined to make it neat and all logic happen only in crud.service.ts using rxjs operators. The end result would be returning one observable of item collections fully formatted.

```
crud.service.ts 

 getTasks() {
   return this.auth.user$.pipe(
    switchMap((value: any) => this.db.collection(`users/${value.uid}/tasks`).snapshotChanges())
  )
}
```

```
component.ts

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fireService.getTasks().subscribe((a: any) => {
      this.tasks = []
      a.forEach((b: any) => {
        let item: any = b.payload.doc.data();
        item.id = b.payload.doc.id;
        item.defaultState = true
        this.tasks.push(item)
      })
    })
}
```

Comment: You can use `map` operator in your pipe and move the `item` part of the code there. And in your subscription, you just assign the `tasks` array.

Comment: If you could please post the working code as the answer, I can accept and close the question straight away :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service should process the data and shape it :

```
 getTasks() {
   return this.auth.user$.pipe(
    switchMap((value: any) => 
    this.db.collection(`users/${value.uid}/tasks`).snapshotChanges()),
    map( (val) => 
           val.map( (inner) => {
              let item: any = b.payload.doc.data();
              item.id = b.payload.doc.id;
              item.defaultState = true;
              return item;
            }))
  )
```

And in your subscription, you just assign the value.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fireService.getTasks().subscribe((a: any) => {
      this.tasks = a;     
    })
}
```

Comment: It says switchMap is a deprecated symbol for some reason? Also, the code doesn't seem to work :( I'm really sorry but I am new to the concepts of ReactiveX.

Comment: I actually tried many other ways, the problem looks easy at the surface of it, but may be a little complex.

Comment: @ParthSandeepAgarwal it says deprecated because I forgot to place a `)` after `.snapshotChanges()`